# Swashbuckle how to add OneOf declaration to OpenAPI 3

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swashbuckle

I have a request object that can be of 2 string types "A" or "B".

*Note: This is a simpler example of what I really want. An enum won't work for me here.*

```cs
public class SampleRequest
    {
        //Can only be "A" or "B"
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to create a schema filter that can output as the OpenAPI "OneOf" attribute.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-5.5.5

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/#oneof

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#schema-filters

```cs
public class CustomSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {

            schema.OneOf = new List<OpenApiSchema>
            {

                new OpenApiSchema {Type = "string", Description = "A"},
                new OpenApiSchema {Type = "string", Description = "B"}
            };
            
        }
    }
```

When running the swagger, swagger-ui correctly renders the "oneOf" description:

```
oneOf: List [ OrderedMap { "type": "string", "description": "A" }, OrderedMap { "type": "string", "description": "B" } ]
```

However, I was expecting the value of it to look more like

```
oneOf: [ "A", "B" ]
```

Is this possible? The people reading my swagger documentation aren't going to know what a List of OrderedMap is.

Comment: not sure what is your question here?

Answer (score 11):

In C# .NET Core 5: In order to automatically resolve `oneOf` (polymorphism) at compile-time for your `swagger.json`, add the following line in your `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
     services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {c.UseOneOfForPolymorphism();})
}
```

For everything else, you can follow [the documentation of OpenAPI 3.0](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/inheritance-and-polymorphism/).

Comment: This works if you are using inheritance but if you are using different class for same error code and defined using ProducesResponseType attribute on ActionMethod they are not being shown in schema only last declared one is being picked.

I think OneOf is not meant only for polymorphism, its more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this with a SchemaFilter:

```cs
    public class SampleRequest
    {
        //Can only be "A" or "B"
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
    }
    public class SampleRequestSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(
            OpenApiSchema schema,
            SchemaFilterContext context
        )
        {
            if (context.Type == typeof(SampleRequest))
            {
                var sampleProperty = schema.Properties.FirstOrDefault(
                    c => string.Equals(
                        c.Key,
                        nameof(SampleRequest.Property1),
                        StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
                    )
                );
                if (sampleProperty.Value != null)
                {
                    var oneOfList = new List<OpenApiSchema>();
                    var aSchema = context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(typeof(A),context.SchemaRepository);
                    if (aSchema != null)
                    {
                        oneOfList.Add(aSchema);
                    }
                    var bSchema = context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(typeof(B),context.SchemaRepository);
                    if (bSchema != null)
                    {
                        oneOfList.Add(bSchema);
                    }
                    if (oneOfList.Any())
                    {
                        var oneOfSchema = new OpenApiSchema
                        {
                            Type = "object",
                            OneOf = oneOfList
                        };
                        schema.Properties.Remove(sampleProperty.Key);
                        schema.Properties.Add(sampleProperty.Key, oneOfSchema);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Im using this version of the package:

```xml
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
```