# How to support OneOf(OpenApi) in asp.net core WebApi

Tags: .net-core, swagger, openapi, webapi, nswag

Is there any way I can support oneOf in asp.net core webapi.

Can I support two different schemas in the request body?

[image]
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/#oneof

Comment: Is it the same as mentioned in this post?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61782580/swashbuckle-how-to-add-oneof-declaration-to-openapi-3

Comment: @Chaodeng I am using Nswag in my project.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Kiota: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openapi/kiota/overview

Example:

```
dotnet kiota generate --openapi http://.../swagger.json -l CSharp --output TestApiSdk -c TestApi -n Test.Api.Client
```